# Text I made in Photoshop becomes blurry when exported as JPG or PNG

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, png, jpg

I made an image with Photoshop. The text looks perfect in Photoshop but when I register it in .jpg or .png, the text looks blurry.

I tried everything, but nothing works. The font is Truetype, the resolution 72dpi, and I tried every aliasing setting, but that doesn't work either.

[image]

Comment: Thats jpeg compression aliasing. what compression quality are you using? how are you exporting?

Comment: Your question says you get the same with PNG, but you certainly shouldn't since that is definitely JPG compression.

Comment: If this is a PNG being uploaded to, say Facebook, then the server software is probably re-compressing it as JPG (which would account for the JPG artifacts) and you will have limited or no control over it.

Answer (score 18):

This in not blurriness, but the JPEG compression doing its thing. Strong colour contrasts between irregular shapes are always distorted like this by the compression in a .jpg. We call them 'artefacts'.

You could try to reduce the amount of JPEG compression. Increase the 'quality' slider when you export / save as a .jpg and the results should be better. The higher the quality, the less compression artefacts and the larger the file.

If all else fails, try and export a PNG-24 instead, but be warned that most social media will re-save a .png as a .jpg anyway, and re-compress it. Reintroducing your problem.

Comment: I've noticed the problem seems to be worse with white letters on red background.

Comment: @Andreyu Any bright colour contrast with straight edges that aren't veritcal or horizontal gives .jpg problems. White type on red background is just very common, and for some reason the artefacts show really well on red.

Answer (score -1):

Just found out:
1 Image size - Double you image size in photoshop
2 Export
3 Open the exported JPG file and resize as you wish.